# Alert sound in Vim after placing comments after key mapping in .vimrc

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm trying map the following keys to switch splits in Vim.

```
nnoremap <s-j> <c-w>j  " Shift + j to switch the split below
nnoremap <s-k> <c-w>k  " Shift + k to switch the split above
nnoremap <s-h> <c-w>h  " Shift + h to switch the split on the left
nnoremap <s-l> <c-w>l  " Shift + l to switch the split on the right
```

This works well except I hear an alert sound when performing the switch. For example, there is no alert sound when pressing `Ctrl+w` and then `j`, but there is an alert for `Shift+j`.

I suspect there is an error happened, and don't like just turning off the alert sound without understanding.

Maybe the remapping does more than just `Ctrl+w` + `j`?

Does any vim expert have some thoughts?

Comment: Actually, I notice the alert bell in other key re-mapping... Does the bell here just simply mean I'm pressing a re-mapped keys set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing your comments will likely fix this problem. See `:help :quote`.

Also…

- Why `<s-j>` when you could simply use `J`?
- `:help J`, `:help L`, `:help H`, and `:help K` are all very useful commands. Are you sure you want to override them?

Comment: You are right, `J`, `L`, `H` and `K` commands are useful and I decide to keep them. I change the mapping to `<c-j>`, `<c-l>`, `<c-h>` and `<c-k>` instead. Yes, the alert sounds were caused by the quotes, which were likely recognized as register symbols when placed after the re-mapping statement.